# Mysql query works on 5.5 but not on 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

I'm looking into migrating some DBs from Mysql 5.5 to 5.7.
I've dumped and restored a DB from 5.5 into a 5.7 and now a simple query does not work anymore.

Here below the table desc:

```
mysql> desc compute_currency_cluster_weights;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| FK_fcl_id  | char(16) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| partition  | char(16) | NO   | PRI |                     |       |
| valore     | double   | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| min_cpu    | int(11)  | NO   |     | 1                   |       |
| min_valore | double   | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| max_cpu    | int(11)  | NO   |     | 1                   |       |
| max_valore | double   | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| datestamp  | datetime | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

On the old 5.5 server:

```
mysql> select * FROM compute_currency_cluster_weights WHERE partition='high';
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| FK_fcl_id | partition | valore | min_cpu | min_valore | max_cpu | max_valore | datestamp           |
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+------------+---------------------+
| daint     | high      |      2 |       1 |          2 |       1 |          2 | 2017-01-17 11:11:39 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+------------+---------+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On the new 5.7

```
mysql> select * FROM compute_currency_cluster_weights WHERE partition='high';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'partition='high'' at line 1
```

On both mysql server I can anyway successfully perform this query:

```
mysql> select * FROM compute_currency_cluster_weights WHERE FK_fcl_id='daint';
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| FK_fcl_id | partition | valore               | min_cpu | min_valore           | max_cpu | max_valore           | datestamp           |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| daint     |           |                    1 |       1 |                    1 |       1 |                    1 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 |
| daint     | high      |                    2 |       1 |                    2 |       1 |                    2 | 2017-01-17 11:11:39 |
| daint     | wlcg      | 0.013888888888888888 |       1 | 0.013888888888888888 |       1 | 0.013888888888888888 | 2017-07-18 00:00:00 |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It looks like the issue is with the "partition" field.

I'm not a DBA (as you may see) and I've no clue where to look.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put backticks around `partition` like `` `partition` ``. It's a reserved word since version 5.6.2. See [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html).